# iOS Push notification working when run from server but not working from real device

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I am developing a remote push notification for iOS using php. When I run my code from server using the command `php push_notification.php` (`push_notification.php` is the filename of my api), it is sending the notification successfully. But, when I try to run the api from post man or real device, it is not sending any notification and giving me an error saying `Failed to connect to the APNS server. Error no = 0<br/>`. Here is my code.

```
<?php

   /* sample device token*/
    $id = '9A057567E5208D4471294A0FDFFF777EEE92E2205EBA9334C5ADE5A383F7B344';

    $apnsServer = 'ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195';

    /* Make sure this is set to the password that you set for your private key
    when you exported it to the .pem file using openssl on your OS X */

    $privateKeyPassword = 'password';
    $message = 'Welcome to iOS 10 Push Notifications';
    /* Pur your device token here */
    $deviceToken = $id;
    /* Replace this with the name of the file that you have placed by your PHP
    script file, containing your private key and certificate that you generated
    earlier */
    $pushCertAndKeyPemFile = dirname(__FILE__).'/PushCertificateAndKey.cer';
    $stream = stream_context_create();
    stream_context_set_option($stream,
    'ssl',
    'passphrase',
    $privateKeyPassword);
    stream_context_set_option($stream,
    'ssl',
    'local_cert',
    $pushCertAndKeyPemFile);
    stream_context_set_option( $stream , 'ssl', 'verify_peer', false);

    $connectionTimeout = 60;
    $connectionType = STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT | STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT;
    $connection = stream_socket_client($apnsServer,$errorNumber,$errorString, $connectionTimeout, $connectionType,$stream);
    if (!$connection){
    echo "Failed to connect to the APNS server. Error no = $errorNumber<br/>";
    exit;
    } else {
    echo "Successfully connected to the APNS. Processing...</br>";
    }
    $messageBody['aps'] = array('alert' => $message,
    'sound' => 'default',
    'badge' => 2,
    );
    $payload = json_encode($messageBody);
    $notification = chr(0) .
    pack('n', 32) .
    pack('H*', $deviceToken) .
    pack('n', strlen($payload)) .
    $payload;
    $wroteSuccessfully = fwrite($connection, $notification, strlen($notification));
    if (!$wroteSuccessfully){
    echo "Could not send the message<br/>";
    }
    else {
    echo "Successfully sent the message: ".$message."to device token: ".$id.PHP_EOL;
    }
    fclose($connection);
?>
```

I know there are a lot of issues related to push notification. But I think mine is different in a way that I am able to send notification from my server but not from my device or postman. What is wrong with this and why is it working when I run it from my server and not working on a real device?

Answer (score 2):

You need to check a few things in order to properly test the `Push Notifications` flow.

- Are you using the `Development` or `Production` certificate on the server for sending the `Push Notifications`?
- Are you installing the app directly from `Xcode` or using a `Development (Debug)` or `Production (Release)` build?
- Also make sure that you have installed the APNS certificate installed in `.p12` format on your development machine.

You must notice that an app installed from a development build can only receive notifications from a server with a development certificate.
While a production app can only receive notifications from a server with a production certificate.

Hope this helps